# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The observer is null

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

A user of one of my apps reported this error.  I'm confused as to what it means an how to fix it.  After a bit of googling...still no luck.  Anyone seen this before or know how to fix it?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The observer is null.
at android.database.Observable.unregisterObserver(Observable.java:59)
at android.widget.BaseAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(BaseAdapter.java:42)
at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:256)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onDetachedFromWindow(AbsListView.java:2309)
at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:8197)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1968)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1966)
at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3257)
at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3237)
at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:3185)
at com.aheudev.a.slickdeals.adapters.DealPageAdapter.destroyItem(DealPageAdapter.java:174)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:415)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.completeScroll(ViewPager.java:696)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.computeScroll(ViewPager.java:668)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2434)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9282)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2584)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2582)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2582)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9282)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:419)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1923)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1695)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1410)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2040)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And it came from this function in my PagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
}
```

Comment: I found the answer [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508294/what-is-trigger-this-exception-instance-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-th).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I too was having the same problem and it seems that unregisterDataSetObserver on your DealPageAdapter is being called twice. To fix the problem I overwrote the unregisterDataSetObserver in my Adapter as such

```
@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    if (observer != null) {
        super.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few people who have had your problem [Here](http://markmail.org/message/lbngfvm6iut2aitn) and [Here](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh/issues/19)

From looking at the call stack it looks like your "view" registered a observer that it's now trying to unregister. That observer is no longer there even though it's expected. Hence the error. This might be a bug or it might be related to how you're doing things.

Trying looking through the [Android Source](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android.shtml) to see if you can track it down.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to wrap the ListView and catch the exception. This solution worked for me, and I have yet not found any side effects.

    `public class CustumListView extends ListView {`

```
  public CustumListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    try {
      super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException iae) {

    }
  }
}
```