# textview content is getting trimmerd after viewpager swipe back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager which has 10 fragments.

when i swipe back to 2nd fragment from 9th fragment, textview's content is getting trimmed as shown in below image!

It is only showing first letter of all textviews. 
What's the issue?

[image]

Code ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    int baseId = 0;
    public ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    public int fid;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> checkPointList) {
        super(fm);
        arrayList = checkPointList;

        //        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data",checkPointList);
//        nodesFragment.setArguments(checkPointList);
    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, boolean f) {
        super(fm);

//        this.checkPointList = checkPointList;
//        nodesFragment = new NodesFragment(checkPointList);
//        fragmentList.add(nodesFragment);
//        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data",checkPointList);
//        nodesFragment.setArguments(checkPointList);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        VideoSliderFragment f = new VideoSliderFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(IntentParams.VIDEO_URL, arrayList.get(position));
        bundle.putInt(IntentParams.POSITION, position);
        f.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentList.add(f);
        return f;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
//        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Share some code, please.

Comment: updated in quesn

Comment: Please share the view code for the fragment in which the issue is occurring.

Comment: And where is a layout?

Comment: I usually paint problem views with different colors (set different backgrounds). This way I understand, what views are trimmed, too wide, overlap, etc.

Comment: Also you can try to use `FragmentPagerAdapter` or set `setOffscreenPageLimit(9)`.

Comment: `getItem` is strange. It should get a fragment from a list of fragments that was created in constructor. But you create it every time and add to `fragmentList`. When do you use it? You create `arrayList`, but replace it in the constructor. You shouldn't create it.